# Would an object stop if the only force acting against it is air friction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, projectile, drag

This question has bothered me for some time couple of years ago, so here is the main problem:

> Suppose that an object of mass $m$, is thrown with horizontal velocity $v$ on a horizontal, frictionless, flat surface. There is air friction, so the only force acting against this object is air friction, which is the function $-kv^2$, where $k$ is constant and v is the velocity of the object. What is the distance traveled by this object until it stops (if it does)?

I remember trying to solve this and finding out that the object does not stop, it always has some velocity > 0.

Comment: Why not simply solving the differential equation $m \dot{v}=-k v^2$ yourself?

Comment: It doesn't come to a stop, and it travels an infinite distance as it does so. However, before that actually happens, linear drag is likely to take over, and in the linear drag case, it never comes to a stop but only travels a *finite* distance (so, essentially, it stops once $v$ is "small enough").

Comment: @Hyperon That's what I did back at the time! And that's when I have found out that it does not stop (travels infinite distance). However I remember asking around this and having answers that it does stop, which didn't convince me at the time so here I am seeking for an intuitive answer.

Comment: @CuriousCrypto I would suggest you edit your post to only say “My question is simply the title of my post” and eliminate everything else.

Answer (score 1):

As OP is formulated, it is a "homework like" question, being "off topic" on this site. In view of your later comment ("seeking for an intuitive answer"), I shall take the liberty to reformulate your question in such a way that it becomes "on topic" concerning a physical concept rather than a trivial exercise on a simple differential equation.

First of all, "intuition" is a rather individual notion (e.g. your "intuition" most probably differs from Wolfgang Pauli's or mine). Avoiding thus an "opinion based" answer (being again "off topic"), let me pose the problem in this way: Consider the class of one-dimensional equations of motion  $$m \dot{v} =-k v^\alpha, \qquad \alpha \gt 0,$$ with your phenomenological force $-kv^2$ being the special case $\alpha =2$. Is it possible to find out whether or not the particle comes to a stop after some finite time $\tau$ *without* solving the corresponding differential equation by only using simple *dimensional analysis*?
As $$\left[\frac{k}{m}\right]= \frac{1}{T}\left(\frac{L}{T}    \right)^{1-\alpha},$$ and the only quantities for constructing a *characteristic time* $\tau$ of the problem being the initial velocity $v_0$ and the ratio $k/m$, we find $$\tau= \gamma \frac{m\,  v_0^{1-\alpha}}{k}, \qquad \alpha\ne 1,$$ where $\gamma$ is a dimensionless factor. As this formula diverges for $\alpha \gt 1$ for the obvious special case $v_0 \to 0$, we conclude that we can expect a *finite* stopping time $\tau$ only for $\alpha \lt 1$. This can be checked of course by explicitly solving the differential equation giving $\gamma= 1/(1-\alpha)$ for the dimensionless constant.

Answer (score 0):

$$F = M a = M dv/dt = -K v^2 $$ is a separable differential equation and after separating and integrating both sides $$ \int_{V_i}^{V_f} \frac{M}{v^2} dv = -\int_0^t K d t$$ where $V_i$ is the initial velocity and $V_f$ is the final velocity$$ M \left(\frac{1}{V_i} - \frac{1}{V_f} \right) = - K t $$ $$ t = \frac{M}{K}  \left( \frac{1}{V_f} - \frac{1}{V_i}\right) $$

In the limit that $V_f$ tends to zero, t does indeed tend to infinity according to these equations, but there are limitations to their applicability (See below).

This equation can be rendered as a half life equation by setting $V_f = V_i /2$ and the result is $$ T_{1/2} = \frac{3 M}{V_i K}$$

The velocity at any given time is $${V_f} = \frac{V_i K}{V_i t M +K}$$ and it can be seen that v never quite goes to zero for any finite t.

It's tempting to think that the total distance (x) asymptotically approaches some fixed value, but taking the integral of velocity with respect to time reveals the distance covered goes to infinity as t goes to infinity. The integral with respect to t is $$ x = \int_0^{\infty} v \ dt = \int_0^{\infty}  \frac {V_i M}{v_0 t K + M} dt = \frac{1}{K} \left( \log ({ M + \infty }) - \log ({ M + 0}) \right) = \infty    $$

However, $-Kv^2$ is probably an approximation for high speeds and as  @march points out in the comments, it is likely that the drag function becomes linear at low speeds and in reality the object stop in a finite time and distance.

If we examine the energy balance, the initial energy is $1/2 m v^2$ and the energy equivalent of a non zero friction force acting over an infinite distance is infinite, then energy is not conserved and that confirms that $- K v^2$ almost certainly does not hold at speeds approaching zero. We also know from aero dynamics that fluid flows change from laminar to turbulent at a certain velocity.

The above equations assume a point particle. If we model the object as a cuboid with volume $L *W * H$ and the frontal area as $W * H$ and Density $D = M/(W*H*L)$ we can replace M with $D L$ where L is the length of the object parallel to the motion. This tells us a long thin object with small frontal area and high density will slow down slower.